# PHP imagecopymerge() - one image is stretched

Tags: php, stretching

I'm am trying to add a 50px white margin down the right side of an image by creating an empty image that's 50px wider than the source image and then merging the source image onto it. The problem is that the source image just gets stretched sideways so it's 50px wider!
Maybe I'm using the wrong function to merge the images ...
here's my code

```
    $destImage = $filepath;
#echo "dest image = ".$destImage;
$sourceImage = imagecreatefrompng($filepath);
// dimensions
$src_wide = imagesx($sourceImage);
echo "src_wide=".$src_wide;
$src_high = imagesy($sourceImage);
// new image dimensions with right padding
$dst_wide = $src_wide+50;
echo "dst_wide=".$dst_wide;
$dst_high = $src_high;
// New resource image at new size
$dst = imagecreatetruecolor($dst_wide, $dst_high);
// set white padding color
$clear = array('red'=>255,'green'=>255,'blue'=>255);
// fill the image with the white padding color
$clear = imagecolorallocate( $dst, $clear["red"], $clear["green"], $clear["blue"]);
imagefill($dst, 0, 0, $clear);
// copy the original image on top of the new one
imagecopymerge($dst,$sourceImage,0,0,0,0,$src_wide,$src_high, 100);
imagepng($dst,$destImage,6);
imagedestroy($dst);
chmod($destImage,0775);
```

what am I doing wrong here ??
thanks

Comment: set destination x to 50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's stretching because you are copying it to the full width of the destination image. Instead use

```
imagecopyresampled($dst,$sourceImage,50,0,0,0,$src_wide,$src_high,$src_wide,$src_high);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but that doesn't seem to work. it's still stretching the image. Is there another similar function I could try ?